# How to fix ReactQuery (useQuery) problem that compiles successfully but returns a blank page?

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

I am a beginner at using ReactJS and currently following a video that uses React Query for fetching data from an API. This is the video I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYXvHXOJzwc&list=PLpPqplz6dKxW5ZfERUPoYTtNUNvrEebAR&index=10

I am particularly having errors on the code shown in timestamp 13:01. Here are my React components' source code:

**Home.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import Axios from 'axios';

export const Home = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery(["cat"], () => {
        return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is Home page </h1>
            <p>{ data.fact }</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { Contact } from './Contact';
import { Profile } from './Profile';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query"

function App() {
  const client = new QueryClient();

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <QueryClientProvider client={ client }>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              <Link to="/profile" style={{margin : 10}}>Profile</Link>
              <Link to="/contact" style={{margin : 10}}>Contact</Link>
            </div>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={ <Home/> }></Route>
              <Route path="/profile" element={ <Profile/> }></Route>
              <Route path="/contact" element={ <Contact/> }></Route>
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

This is my **console log** for further information:

[image]

I think I am currently having problems in line 6 of Home.js wherein I am trying to fetch the API data using Axios but I have no clue what the reason is. If anyone also followed this tutorial or encountered the same problem, may I ask how you fixed it? Thank you.

Comment: `data` starts out as `undefined`. Refactor it to `data?.fact`

Comment: Hi, Joshua. That worked. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is going be undefined until the 1st request has succeeded, that's expected behaviour.

Use `isPending` (or `isLoading` on versions before React Query 5) to check if data is loaded before displaying it:

```
export const Home = () => {
    const { data, isPending } = useQuery(["cat"], () => {
        return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is Home page </h1>
            <p>{todos.isPending ? 'Loading...' : data.fact }</p>
            // change above property to 'isLoading' if not using version 5 
        </div>
    );
}
```